# Reading a sequence of integers using map in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

Can someone kindly explain how the following python code is working? This code is reading a series of integers, which are arranged as 3-tuples.

```
inverted_list = map(lambda i: (int(numbers[2 + 3*i]),
                           float(numbers[3 + 3*i]),
                           float(numbers[4 + 3*i]))
                    ,range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3))
```

Exactly how map and lambda works? Is the lambda really required here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, lambda is not really required here, this could also be written as:

```
inverted_list = [(int(numbers[2 + 3*i]),
                  float(numbers[3 + 3*i]),
                  float(numbers[4 + 3*i])) for i in range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3]
```

I'm not going into the math bit of the indexers, since i'm only on my first cup of coffee today, but what `map` does, is apply a function to a sequence, generating a new sequence with the result of the function for each element. The `lambda` is the function, in this case creating a tuple from your numbers. The sequence is the `range` expression, that gives you a list of `i` values that you can use in your indexing expressions (e.g. `3 + 3*i`).

The version of your code snippet @gnibbler and I are showing you is *modern* python. This wasn't around in, say, python 1.5 - so we used `map`, `reduce`, `zip` and other "functional" high order operations. I personally like them a lot, but I guess the're doomed to be replaced for most tasks - the list comprehensions are more expressive in cases like this one!

Answer (score 1):

It's roughly equivalent to this list comprehension. Using map with the lambda will run a little slower than the list comprehension though

```
inverted_list = [((int(numbers[2 + 3*i]), float(numbers[3 + 3*i]), 
                float(numbers[4 + 3*i])) for i in range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3)]
```

Beats me why you'd multiply `i` by 3 everywhere though,

```
inverted_list = [((int(numbers[i]), float(numbers[1+i]), 
                float(numbers[2+i])) for i in range(2, len(numbers), 3)]
```

Comment: Its because, the first 2 numbers are not part of the sequence. I think it is effectively running a loop, starting at the third element of the series. I was just confused that, whether the map/lambda performing any other operation here.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a list

```
(numbers[2],numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[2 + 3],numbers[3 + 3], numbers[4 + 3], ...., numbers[2 + 3*((len(numbers) -2)/3)],numbers[3 +  3*((len(numbers) -2)/3)], numbers[4 + 3*((len(numbers) -2)/3)]
```

mapping the range:

```
range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3)
```

to tuples with lambda.

One way would be to use list comprehension and iterate range starting at 2 with size 3 step:

```
[(int(numbers[i]), float(numbers[i + 1]), float(numbers[i + 2])) for i in range(2,len(numbers), 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers that explain nicer or more modern ways to express this, but I would like to demonstrate exactly what the lambda and map do in terms of more basic features. First of all, here's your example:

```
inverted_list = map(lambda i: (int(numbers[2 + 3*i]),
                               float(numbers[3 + 3*i]),
                               float(numbers[4 + 3*i]))
                    ,range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3))
```

To make things a bit clearer, I'll separate out the arguments to map. This is equivalent; all I have changed is to calculate each of the arguments to map in a separate statement:

```
func = lambda i:(int(numbers[2 + 3*i]),
                 float(numbers[3 + 3*i]),
                 float(numbers[4 + 3*i]))
sequence = range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3)
inverted_list = map(func, sequence)
```

`lambda` is simply a way to express a simple function inside an expression. We can replace it with a regular function without changing the effect:

```
def func(i):
    return (int(numbers[2 + 3*i]),
            float(numbers[3 + 3*i]),
            float(numbers[4 + 3*i]))
sequence = range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3)
inverted_list = map(func, sequence)
```

`map` is what is called a "higher order function", a function that takes another function as an argument. `map` will loop through each item in `sequence`, call `func` with that item as an argument, take whatever the function returns and append it to a new list.*

If you wanted to do the same thing without higher order functions or generator expressions, you could write this out the long way:

```
def func(i):
    return (int(numbers[2 + 3*i]),
            float(numbers[3 + 3*i]),
            float(numbers[4 + 3*i]))
sequence = range(0, (len(numbers) - 2)/3)
inverted_list = []
for item in sequence:
    inverted_list.append(func(item))
```

The benefit of lambda is that you can express in one expression something that would otherwise require introducing temporary variables and possibly declaring the function some way before the point you want to use it. The benefit of map is similarly that you can write in one expression something that would otherwise require temporary variables and a loop.

(*) From Python 3, map actually returns an iterator, not a list.